# How do add a custome .el file to my path?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to create a custome ''.el'' path for Emacs. I'm following [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GenericMode) instructions about generic mode. When I try to load the mode Emacs doesn't find it. (I have placed the file in `.emacs.d` folder). So I tried what is explained [here](http://edward.oconnor.cx/2005/09/installing-elisp-files) which only cause an error when Emacs load.

While at it. Is there a way to reload my init file while Emacs run?

I'm trying this on arch-linux. When I try to load the file using `require` I can an error that the file does not exist. I tried load instead and this work.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to mention what OS you are running and what any error messages say.

Comment: @Peter.O: Thanks. I want to reload the setting, not to re-read it into buffer

Comment: @Yotam: Have a look at this link: 
[How can I reload .emacs after changing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580650/how-can-i-reload-emacs-after-changing-it)  ...or [How can I load changes to my .emacs without rebooting Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580650/how-can-i-reload-emacs-after-changing-it)  .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your `.emacs`

```
;;; Set location for external packages.
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")
```

Answer (score 1):

The subdirectory under your emacs installation called

> "site-lisp"

is where custom libraries are stored. Copy your .el file there and in your .emacs file, you can load the file without specifying the path. like this:

```
(load-library "my-file")
```

where my-file is my-file.el

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the end parenthesis and evaluate the buffer using either `C-x-C-e` or you can use `M-x eval-buffer`